# Temporary disable physics from CCSprite

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

I'm currently discovering Cocos2D in combination with SpriteBuilder and I'm making stuff bounce around.
It's quite fun :) 
What I'm trying to figure out is the following : 
- On SpriteBuilder, I create a CCSprite, and I enable physics for this one.
- I can invoke it in XCode, and do whatever I want with it. Plus, the sprite is reacting accordingly to the physics settings applied to it. Great.

Now, what I would like to do is to disable the physics from this sprite in the code. I don't find a method in the Cocos2D API that would do the trick.

Can you help me out ?

Thank you for your time and help ;)

Comment: I think you can do the trick with: sprite.physicsBody.sensor = TRUE;

Comment: Man, this is just great, thank you. Have all my Internets :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write the correct answer then:

```
sprite.physicsBody.sensor = TRUE;
```